# How can I create a TableLayout with 4 columns?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I am having problems creating a table layout with 4 columns, that span horizontally.

I want my Row to look like this:

AAPL | 200.00 | Image Divider | 1.53 (+1.5%)

I want the 200.00 to be right aligned, as well as the 1.53(+1.5%).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stocks_gradient" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/priceText" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameText" android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/nameText" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Symbol" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="100dp" android:textColor="#4871A8" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/priceText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="5dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameText" android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#4871A8" />
        <ImageView android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/changeText"
            android:id="@+id/verticalDivider" android:background="@drawable/vertical_divider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="48dp"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/changeText" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceText" android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="18sp" android:text="3.07(+1.08%)" android:padding="12dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`android:layout_toLeftOf`, `android:layout_toRightOf`, and `android:layout_below` are attributes for use with RelativeLayout. You do not have a `RelativeLayout`. Hence, those attributes as used in your XML above are doing you no good.

To make a row with four columns, have four children of the `TableRow` widget.

I am not completely clear on how you would achieve your right-aligned effect. Probably `android:gravity` will get you there, but I have a suspicion that the problem is more complicated than that.

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: No. Note the position of your `</TableRow>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity` should be all you need here since your TextView is already in `width=fill_parent`, e.g. it will align the text to the right inside the view.

Otherwise you can also play with `android:layout_gravity="right"`, e.g. if you have a view with `width=wrap_content` and you need to tell the container how to align it.